# remover un objeto dentro de un objeto que esta en una lista

Tags: java

tengo un problema necesito eliminar un objeto que esta dentro de un objeto y de momento llevo esto, RadioReloj es una clase y Reloj tambien, eliminador es un metodo que esta en la clase radioreloj.

```
   public void eliminadorDeReloj(ArrayList<RadioReloj> lista){
    if(lista.isEmpty()){
        System.out.println("No hay radiorelojes en la lista");
    }else{
        for(int i=0; i<lista.size(); i++) {
            if((lista.get(i).isOriginal()) == false){
                lista.remove(lista.get(i).reloj);
                System.out.println("Reloj eliminado de la radio con exito");
            }else{
                System.out.println("No hay relojes falsos");
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: La función `remove` del `ArrayList<RadioReloj>` elimina un elemento `RadioReloj` y no lo que sea que tienes en `RadioReloj.reloj`. Si `RadioReloj.reloj` es un objeto de la clase `Reloj`, lo que tendrías que hacer para eliminarlo es igualarlo a `null` y no ejecutar el `remove`.

Comment: si, tienes toda la razón después de intentar varias cosas lo mas cerca a "eliminar" fue cambiar su estado a null.

Answer (score 0):

En este caso lo ideal es que remuevas el objeto de la lista indicado por su indice `lista.get(i)` :

```
    ...
    if((lista.get(i).isOriginal()) == false){
        //lista.remove(lista.get(i).reloj);
        lista.remove(lista.get(i)); //Remueve objeto de lista
        System.out.println("Reloj eliminado de la radio con exito");
    }else{
        System.out.println("No hay relojes falsos");
    }
    ...
```